# What's the use of the table extended_geometry_columns in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

Sometimes my PostGIS database creates a extended_geometry_columns table. After some search i've not found what is the use of this table.

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4 and PostGIS 1.3.3

This is the definition of the table

```
CREATE TABLE extended_geometry_columns (
    f_table_schema character varying(265) NOT NULL,
    f_table_name character varying(256) NOT NULL,
    x_min double precision,
    y_min double precision,
    x_max double precision,
    y_max double precision,
    CONSTRAINT extended_geometry_columns_pkey PRIMARY KEY (f_table_schema, f_table_name)
```

);

AFAIK the only tools that are connecting to the database are pgadmin3/psql,  [gvSIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GvSIG), and some custom python scripts (that i'm sure not create the table).

Thanks

Comment: I've been using PostGIS forever since 0.8, and I don't recall there ever being an extended_geometry_columns.  What columns does it have in it?  You don't have other software that writes to the db like ArcGIS or MapInfo.  I recall those two create additional tables though I think they created them in their own special schema (sde, mapinfo).

Comment: That is kind of weird.  What is especially strange about this table you have is that there is no geometry column in it and a table could have more than one geometry column.  So the assumption it is making about the x,y min/max I have no idea what name of column it would be assuming.  Is it possible that it is a gvSig plugin (not gvSig core)

Comment: I also grep the not official plugins that i'm using. I remove the table and i try to catch the moment when is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever it is, it's not PostGIS creating it. I've just downloaded the [source for 1.3.3](http://postgis.refractions.net/download/postgis-1.3.3.tar.gz) (you really should be using a more up-to-date version...)

Unzipped it:

```
tar xzf postgis-1.3.3.tar.gz
cd postgis-1.3.3
```

and grepped for `_geometry_column`:

```
grep _geometry_column -iR *
```

And apart from a few references to the function `fix_geometry_columns()` and `probe_geometry_columns()` nothing has come up.

What other software are you using on this database? Like you, I found Google only turned up links to this question, so it may be that if you are using closed-source software like ArcGIS, it is something that software adds to speed up some process or other.

Comment: I grep the gvSIG code and i not find reference to that table... I'm not sure what app can be creating it. Thanks